# how can I use average function usage with Count function in Linq to EF

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to use Average function with Count in my Linq to EF query. So if I have to explain what I try to realize with my code part in t-sql for more clear understanding, You can take look below them,

```
select s.SalesPointId, count(*) as ipp
from ScoreItem si
       inner join Score s on s.Id = si.ScoreId
where si.ResearchGroupType = 0 and si.IsValidForSalesPoint = 1
group by s.SalesPointId
select avg(ipp)
from (
select s.SalesPointId, count(*) as ipp
from ScoreItem si
       inner join Score s on s.Id = si.ScoreId

where si.ResearchGroupType = 0 and si.IsValidForSalesPoint = 1
group by s.SalesPointId
)
```

As a consequence I have wrote below code in Linq query,

```
List<CvmNameAndValue> AnatolianSalesHeadshipIPPScore = (from si in db.ScoreItem
     join s in db.Score on si.ScoreId equals s.Id
     join sp in db.SalesPoint on s.SalesPointId equals sp.Id
     where (si.ResearchGroupType == ResearchGroupType.ScoreCard && si.IsValidForSalesPoint && sp.CompanyId == ContextData.User.CompanyId && s.ProjectPeriodId == ProjectPeriodId && spIds.Contains(sp.Id))
group s by s.SalesPointId into g
select new CvmNameAndValue
{
Name = SystemSetting.Label_AnatolianSalesHeadshipIPPScore,
Value = g.Average(x => db.Score.Count()).ToString()
})
.ToList();

retVal.Data.DataGroup = AnatolianSalesHeadshipIPPScore.ToList();

return retVal;
```

But, Unfortunately they didn't return same result for me, so if you have any suggestion about my logic mistakes, please feel to free and share with me,

Comment: There are extra three conditions in LINQ if you compare with your SQL query.  sp.CompanyId == ContextData.User.CompanyId && s.ProjectPeriodId == ProjectPeriodId && spIds.Contains(sp.Id)

Comment: I know that because I needed them, and also sql queries just simple for explain what I want to do with my linq statement for developers who helps me, :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have solved my problem, so if you need such as thing, it can be solve your problem,

```
double AnatolianSalesHeadshipIPPScore = 0;

AnatolianSalesHeadshipIPPScore = (from si in db.ScoreItem
                        join s in db.Score on si.ScoreId equals s.Id
                        join sp in db.SalesPoint on s.SalesPointId equals sp.Id
where (si.ResearchGroupType == ResearchGroupType.ScoreCard && si.IsValidForSalesPoint && sp.CompanyId == ContextData.User.CompanyId && s.ProjectPeriodId == ProjectPeriodId)
                    group si by s.SalesPointId into g
                    select new
                    {
                    sid = g.Key,
                    count = g.Count()
}).Average(m => m.count);
```